# Jquery dialog box - doesn't fade out before closing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have div(box) on my page and I'm using this script to display div as dialog box. Inside that div I have a hyper link, On click of the hyper link I want to fade out the dialog box and close.. The content of the dialog fades out, but the border of the dialog box remains same. If I add  $("#box").dialog('close') to the click function after fadeto there is no effect.. it just closes the dialog box completely. Any help? using jquery-ui-1.7.2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $("a#later").click(function () { 

                $("#box").fadeTo('slow', 0);
                 })
             });
            $(function () {
                $("#box").dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    width: 500,
                    modal: true,

                });
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about

```
$("#box").fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
  $("#box").dialog('close');
});
```

You want the close to happen after the fade finishes, correct?

Comment: That's what I call it as Awesome!

Comment: This little ditty is just what I needed, and works well in chrome and FF. Haven't done any IE tests yet.

Comment: actually, `$("#box").dialog("widget").fadeTo(...)` is better because the fade animation applies on the whole box, not just the inside.

Answer (score 3):

try this, it might work:

```
$("a#later").click(function () {
   $("#box").fadeTo('slow', function() {
       $("#box").dialog("close")
   });
});
```

Comment: No.. it just closes, no fade to effect.

Comment: you are very close.. See the answer below.. the FadTo also needs a second parameter for the speed.

Answer (score 2):

I try the code of some Richard below and it works.
You can provide the effect name as a string:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  hide: "fadeOut"
});
```

or you can provide a hash if you have additional options, such as:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  hide: {effect: "fadeOut", duration: 5000}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
            $(function () {
                $("#box").dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    width: 500,
                    modal: true,
                    show: 'blind',
                    hide: 'fade'
                });
            });
```

Check out the example here: [Animated Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated)

Comment: Aw Man.. It doesn't even load the dialog now, it hides by default :)

Comment: Now it loads with a fade in effect.. it won't even close the dialog

Comment: That's really strange. Try removing 'show' option and check the link I posted to see how effects work and what are possible values for effect.

Answer (score 1):

this is my code:

```
$(function() {
$( "a#link-id" ).click(function(){$(".ui-dialog").fadeOut(2000)})});
```

this is working script :). You don't need to click on 'close' button.

Comment: But if there is another dialog open, it will fade out both!